# Unable to retrieve domain_public user information via directory api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have several clients. All of them are able to retrieve their domain_public user information via directory api using their own credential. Then, one of the client always return a resource not found error even the account is valid. However, when I tried with an admin user with admin_view, everything work fine.  Only domain_public viewType return error. Anybody have this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please confirm that contact sharing is enabled for the domain:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/60218?hl=en

As well as for the user they are attempting to retrieve:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/1285988